# QGIS labelling - stop label background shapes from overlapping

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have labels which use background shapes to help identify categories, the shapes need to follow the text not the feature. I would like the label placement to avoid overlapping my backgrounds - can this be done?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the Placement Mode to "Around Point" instead of Cartographic (In Layer Properties -> Labels -> Placement)?

Comment: @AndreGeo just tried - doesn't help

Comment: There is a blocking option in the label drop down to try to keep labels off the points. 
 There are settings in the Rendering - Overlapping Labels to keep labels off each other.   You can also manually move labels.

Comment: @John it's the backgrounds overlapping that is the issue not the features or the text of the labels themselves. A blocking layer doesn't stop the backgrounds from overlapping the features. The overlappping setting also doesn't appear to account for backgrounds.

Comment: How are the background shapes set up in QGIS? You may want to attach a link to a sample of your data/style so that people aren't trying to guess how you have set it up.

Comment: @TomBrennan drawing a background is an option under labelling